# Applying CSS on class with variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm generating class name from server side like:

```
<p class="level_1">List item 1</p>
<p class="level_2">List item 2</p>
<p class="level_3">List item 3</p>
<p class="level_1">List item 1</p>
<p class="level_2">List item 2</p>
<p class="level_1">List item 1</p>
```

and I expect the output with indentation such that it looks like:

```
List item 1
   List item 2
      List item 3
List item 1
   List item 2
List item 1
```

The syntax for class name is like `level_$i` where `$i` is variable and it can go to any level (starting from 1 to n). So how can I apply CSS for indentation in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do for loops in pure CSS. Consider using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for that purpose. Here's a tutorial on LESS [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature)

You can achieve this using jQuery ... see the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j6cpsug0/3/) I prepared for you.

```
var i= 1,
    val= 0;

$('[class^=level_]').each(function(){

$('.level_' + i).css('padding-left',val+'px');
    i++;
    val += 20;
});
```

Comment: `Using less.js in the browser is great for development, but it's not recommended for production` - Official docs

Comment: If there's no solution in CSS for such situation, then suggest me in which way should I return the class name from server?

Comment: Again ... that wouldn't be accomplished with CSS alone ... what server-side programming language are you using?

Comment: Can it be done using jQuery such that it creates CSS when the DOM has loaded? I use Perl on server side.

Comment: See edit ... posted an answer to your problem using jQuery ... let me know if this is what you intended to do ...

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but it looks correct to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 solutions:

1. You can generate CSS style automatically while you are generating list (using PHP)
2. You can use javascript/jquery to parse elements and create appropriate rules dynamically. Here's JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zaviqeyavico/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. I'll prefer jQuery :)